# Does Dreamy Luigi get the benefits of boots worn by waking Luigi?

Tags: mario-luigi-dream-team

In *Mario & Luigi: Dream Team* if I equip boots or a hammer with special effects on Luigi does Dreamy Luigi also get the benefits of the special effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Dreamy Luigi inherits every benefit from Luigi's equipment, although every in-battle drawback such as the damage self-inflicted from a Dark Boot or a Dark Hammer is applied to Mario.

Comment: So if Dreamy Luigi has iron boots or the iron hammer equipped, then the effect of random iron balls falling on an enemy would also carry over to Mario's actions?

Comment: As far as I've seen, the special effects do carry over. Yay for digging up old answers. I just feel like this one deserves being accepted.